# Having trouble with objects and classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, object, c++14

So, I defined the method displayStudInfo in the 'Student' Class and called it in the main function. But I'm getting the error "Function not declared in this scope". Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and what I can do to solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Student{

  public:
    int age;
    string name;


    void enterInfo(){

    cout << "Enter your age = " ; cin >> age;
    cout << "Enter your name = "; cin >> name;

    }


    void displayStudInfo(Student s)
    {
        cout << "Age = " << s.age << ", name=" << s.name << endl;
    }

};




int main(){

    int size;
    Student stud[100];
    Student abir;

    abir.enterInfo();
    displayStudInfo(abir);

}
```

Comment: Make `displayStudInfo` as `friend` ?

Comment: Please, note that (non-static) member functions always get an additional argument which might be unnoticed by you - the object which is noted before `.` (or `->` in case of object pointer). E.g. `abir.enterInfo();` - `abir` is the object the member function `enterInfo()` is called for and becomes `this` inside of function. Hence, all member variables are accessible via `this` implicitly or explicitly: `cin >> age;` is effectively the same as `cin >> this->age;`. Are you sure that `displayStudInfo()` should have an argument `Student s`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `void displayStudInfo(Student s)` is a member function of `Student` so you have to call it on an instance of `Student`, the same way you did with `enterInfo`.

You can solve that in different ways. One way is to make that member function a free function by moving it out of the body of the `Student`

```
class Student{

  public:
    // … 
};

void displayStudInfo(Student s)
{
  cout << "Age = " << s.age << ", name=" << s.name << endl;
}

int main(){
    // … 

    displayStudInfo(abir);

}
```

`displayStudInfo` is, in fact, a good candidate for a free function. Or you make it `static` which is similar to a free function, and access the static member function using `Student::displayStudInfo(abir)`.

The other way would be to call `displayStudInfo` on `abir` in that case you don't need the `Student` argument, as `abir` is implicitly passed to `displayStudInfo`.

```
class Student{

  public:
    // … 

    void displayStudInfo()
    {
      cout << "Age = " << age << ", name=" << name << endl;
    }

};

int main(){
    // … 

    abir.displayStudInfo();
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning to display the values of object by calling the method on object and passing same as parameter?

Answer (score 3):

`void displayStudInfo(Student s)` hidden in side class.
So, its not accessible in main().

Try:

```
 void displayStudInfo()
    {
        cout << "Age = " << age << ", name=" << name << endl;
    }
```

call in main():

```
abir.displayStudInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, all member functions implicitly receive a parameter which points to the current object. This parameter is the [this pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this).

Therefore, it doesn't make sense for you to specify an additional (explicit) parameter for the object in your definition of the function `displayStudInfo`.

It would make sense to rewrite the function definition to

```
void displayStudInfo()
{
    cout << "Age = " << age << ", name=" << name << endl;
}
```

and to call it with

`abir.displayStudInfo();`

instead of

`displayStudInfo(abir);`

Alternatively, you could make the function `displayStudInfo` a non-member function, by putting it outside the declaration of class Student. In that case, you would have to keep the explicit parameter, because that parameter is only passed implicitly to member functions.